# Foreign Tax Credit / form 1116

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-credit

I have a foreign retirement income. Income tax is withheld at source in a foreign country. As I have to file form 1116 to get the FTC (foreign tax credit) I need to know if such retirement is a “passive category income” or a “general category income” as I have to fill the correct box on Form 1116.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but [Taxes for expats](https://www.taxesforexpats.com/articles/retirement/is-foreign-retirement-income-taxable.html) says that "Income derived from bonds, IRAs, rental properties, and stocks are considered passive types of income"

Comment: What type of 'retirement income' are you receiving, specifically? It may make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

retirement income is treated as passive income. In the US, "earned income" is the other side of passive income.